# How do I share my Windows Music Library with my Linux Library?

Tags: linux, music, music-player

I'm running a dual-boot laptop with `Windows 7` and `Kali Linux`. As hard as it was to re-partition my hard drive without re-installing Windows (Which by the way took a lot of research and time), I now have the problem of getting my both OS to access each others' libraries (Music, Documents, etc.) so I don't have to go through the inconvenient process of manually finding my files. I want my music files from Windows to end up in the Music files section of Kali Linux if that's possible.

I have done a good bit of googling, but I did not find a solution to my question in the title. What I'm trying to do is get my music library from windows to show up in my Linux music library so I can access my music from Kali. I have tried to create a hard link in Linux, Share my music folder in Windows with everybody and turn on file sharing, and creating a symbolic link in Linux, but nothing worked. I just want to be able to access my music in the same manner as I access my music in Windows.

Comment: make sure your NTFS partition is mounted at startup

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie at linux still. But how would that help? My NTFS partition from windows is not mounted at startup. That being said, I can always mount it from Linux after it boots with Nautils. I misstated my question I guess. I can access all files from my Windows drive. What I was trying to do was get my Music library in Windows to show up in my Linux Music Library. This is not a file access issue, but rather a convenience I wish to have.

Comment: The symbolic link approach didn't work? Could you tell us more about that?

Comment: By the way, Kali is not a distribution recommended for begginers. You may want to use a more friendly and easy-to-use distribution such as [Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com/), [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/) or [Zorin OS](https://zorinos.com/).

Comment: I tried to make a symbolic link, and like I said, I'm still a bit of a newbie, and when it created, it said it was broken and sent it to trash. When trying to set it up, I tried mounting my Windows partition, and then writing out the target to my Music folder in Windows with the directory being in my Linux Music folder. I have a feeling that I might not have set it up correctly. After it didn't work, I abandoned the idea of a link and went after another method. If the link approach will work, what would I have to do to make the link work?

Comment: I imagine I would have to set up Kali to mount my Windows drive automatically at boot in order for the link to work?

Comment: I wrote an answer with what I believe is the correct approach. Please tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kramer's approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444547/243481) is really good (and I recommend that if you have the opportunity), but it has the disadvantage that you need to repartition your drive.

You can avoid that by using symbolic links on Linux:

```
ln -s /path/to/windows/library /path/to/linux/library
```

That way your files will remain in your Windows partition but you'll be able to access them on Linux the same way you do it on Windows.

Note that you need to mount the Windows partition and it may be needed to remove/rename your old Linux libraries before creating the symlinks, or those will be placed inside the Linux directories:

```
rm -r ~/Documents ~/Music ~/Pictures ~/Videos
```

Comment: Ok, I will try your solution right now. Give me a minute, I gotta boot into linux.

Comment: When doing the directory to Windows, I use /dev/sda# like I've been using instead of C:?

Comment: @KALI99 No, don't use `/dev/sda`. If the partition is mounted automatically, it should appear in the `/mnt` or `/media` directory. Use that path if it exists. If not, you will need to mount it manually.

Comment: Thank you very much nxnev, that worked. Although I had to manually mount the NTFS volume to /mnt, it worked.

Comment: @KALI99 That's great, I'm glad it worked. You may want to write a small cronjob/script to automatically mount the Windows partition at startup.

Comment: I went into disks and edited the mount settings to automatically mount at /mnt on startup.

Answer (score 1):

EXT partitions are not readable by Windows but FAT and NTFS partitions are readable by Linux.

When installing your linux, create one EXT partition for the Linux OS and 1 NTFS partition for Windows OS and another for the user storage (which can be either NTFS, Fatex or FAT32).

Then you need to create the mountpoints at your linux box for the NTFS OS partition and the file storage parittion (Windows will mount them by default). A nice guide to accomplish this: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-mount-partition-with-ntfs-file-system-and-read-write-access

Anyway, if you are a noobie and installing one of the major Linux flavors: i.e. Ubuntu or Fedora, if you install following this order the mounting part will be performed by the Linux set up script:

1. Start your PC using the Windows CD or USB installer
2. Divide your HD in at least 4 parts

   - 1 NTFS for Windows OS
   - 1 File Sotorage (FAT or NTFS)
   - 1 blank (this will be used for Linux EXT partition)
   - 1 small blank (1-2 GBs for Linux SWAP)
3. Complete the installation and turn off
4. Boot your PC with the linux CD or USB installer
5. follow the steps and use the partitioning assistant

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. Will this allow me to access my music in Linux (From a sidebar in Nautils) much in the same way I access my music in windows (from a sidebar in Windows Explorer)?

Comment: well, you will need a Widget or something to do that in Nautilus I guess; I am not very familiar with it as I use plain bash and XFCE. But yes, you will be able to access the filesystem containing your music and bookmark the folder(s) in Nautilus